# How to use the HarperDB upsert() function in python

Tags: python, upsert

I have been trying to use the HarperDB upsert() function (HarperDB object) on a python dev but I haven't found any API implementation of that function on the current packages. Have you ever used it?

It seems that that the upsert() is only available on HarperDBTable objects but I can't understand when/how to use both HarperDBTable and HarperDB classes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.